# How to prevent sending repetitive requests in the AngularJS ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

In AngularJS ng-repeat I have a model array with a specific IMG field for each

item and an input for filtering the model.

```
var model = [
  {id:1,IMG:"img1.jpg",text:"text1"},
  {id:2,IMG:"img2.jpg",text:"text2"}
];
//Filter by text: 
<input type="text" ng-model="filterKey.text"/>
//repeat on model array based on filterKey
<tr ng-repeat="(CRI,row) in model | filter:filterKey">
  <td>
    <img ng-src="row.IMG"/>
  </td>
</tr>
```

At the first When the filterKey is null then all IMGs requested from a server and

it's ok. if I write 'text3' in the input then the AngularJS can't match any

items for that and remove all ng-repeat elements. after that, I write

't' in the input and the AgularJS sends other requests to get filtered

IMGs(because the ng-repeat recreates all elements).

I don't need to send requests to get IMGs that is requested at the first.

The model contains more than 1000 items and in each process send multiple

requests to get IMGs that is requested in previous steps.

How can I handle this issue?

Comment: Is this really an issue? Surely the images are cached.

Comment: @George. The caching is disabled for some reason.

Comment: From where you areloading the data? On page load you should load the data  not on the texboxchange event.